# How to avoid unchecked-conversion-warning in Java, if you use legacy libraries?

Tags: java, generics, warnings

I like the generics-feature in java and use it often. But I have a problem, if I use libraries that aren't yet aware of generics. An example are servlets. If you use `ServletRequest.getParameterMap()` the result will be a raw map, but it includes only `String` as keys and `String[]` as values. So I want to assign it to a `Map<String, String[]>`. But for this assignment I get an warning. How can I avoid this warning with the language, not by simply suppressing the warning with the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As others have said the warnings cannot be avoided except by suppressing them. The issue IMHO is that either you have to litter your code with annotations that apply to small scope or ignore them globally and risk errors.

IIRC there is a proposal to generate warnings where the raw types are being returned instead of at the call.

Meanwhile, I think the best approach is to use a wrapper method so that the warnings are limited to a single place, where it is safe to ignore them:

```
class NoWarn {
  public static Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap(ServletRequest r) 
  {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, String[]> result = r.getParameterMap();
    return result;
  }
}
```

**Note**
This answer was edited with a comment that annotations cannot be inside method bodies. That is incorrect, the above is syntactically correct. I have reverted the change.

Comment: I hope that the proposal you mentioned will be implemented fast (Java7?), because that would clearly solve my problem.

Comment: The edit would be correct if "result" were declared outside of the method... In that case you'd need to move the annotation to the line before the method.

Comment: @Manius your comment confused me for a bit (this being a 10 year old answer perhaps), until I realized that the annotation is currently on the variable definition.

Answer (score 8):

The cleanest thing you can do is to encapsulate the conversion from legacy to generic code and suppress the warning only there.

E.g. you could put a generic facade on your legacy library, though this might not always be worthwhile.

Comment: +1 Write a boilerplate generified wrapper around the legacy API and slap warning suppressions on that.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I avoid this warning with the
>   language, not by simply suppressing
>   the warning with the
>   SuppressWarnings-annotation.

The annotation **is** the way to avoid the warning with the language. There is no other way.

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this question as I was also trying to figure out a way to avoid using the suppress annotation in such cases. I found another alternative which I thought was worth mentioning:

```
    Map<?, ?> map = servletRequest.getParameterMap();
    String[] values = (String[]) map.get("key");
```

We are basically using wildcard '?' to indicate that the map can have any type of key and value.

Potential downside I see here is that we are doing an explicit cast while fetching values, which I think will result in a slight performance overhead during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. The warning will appear unless you suppress it, or filter it from your IDE's warnings list.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i just turned off all generic warnings and im happy :) You could also turn off serialVersionUID warning since many people dont use serialVersionUID.

in Eclipse - Window/Perferences/Java/Compiler/Errors/Warnings and turn off all Generic types.

P.S. Many bad warnings make you ignore all the warnings and some might be usefull.

Comment: I use warnings as a possibility for improvement. I don't get many warnings, because I fix them all on the way. Normally the unchecked-conversion-warnings are very helpful to find code-parts that can be improved. But in this case I don't see a way without suppressing this warning.

Comment: you are lucky, i now have 61 warnings in project, even unused imports warning. i wont fix it since they are not in my code, so Ive closed the Problems Tab and just look for yellow tags in my source code.

Comment: I fix warnings also in code of others in the same project. If problems occur we discuss the rules for the checkers.

Answer (score 0):

as others said, the only way to get rid of this warning is to suppress it.

the best practice is to encapsulate the warning using methods and classes.

but with other warnings, always try to solve the problem that are making them, like remove unused imports and etc... it makes your application leaner and better.

happy coding