# Java class won't work outside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings, textpad

My program runs fine under eclipse. If I open it with the textPad and compile it, I get this message:

> Note: C:\Users\Aezur\Desktop\Project2\SummerQ1.java uses unchecked or
>   unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

It says that has compiled successfully, but it doesn't run.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's a warning, not a compile error.  I assume it's creating a .class file?  What do you mean by "it won't run"?

Comment: How do you run your application? What happened when you cannot run application? Warning doesn't affect compile stage at all.

Comment: what does it say when you try to execute the program? It should rum if it has compiled successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just Warring,do not have any affect on compilation or execution.
Accorind to [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

```
-Xlint:unchecked  
Give more detail for unchecked conversion warnings that are mandated by the Java Language Specification.
```

Generally This comes up in Java 5 and later if you're using collections without type specifiers.
Example :
using `Arraylist()` instead of `Arraylist<String>()`.

You can avoid that warring by using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

```
class NoWarn {
   public static Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap(ServletRequest r) 
   {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Map<String, String[]> result = r.getParameterMap();
      return result;
    }
 }
```

For more information please look into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130433/how-to-avoid-unchecked-conversion-warning-in-java-if-you-use-legacy-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find compiler behavior from Eclipse vs standalone compiling varies because:

- Eclipse has it's own internal compiler; it doesn't use the standard Oracle Java compiler.
- The Eclipse Java compiler allows a relatively high degree of settings to ignore, warn or generate an errora for many coding issues.